# When I build project in Android Studio it throws an error of com.payumoney.sdkui.ui.utils does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-studio, payumoney

When i build project in android studio it's throw an error: **package com.payumoney.sdkui.ui.utils does not exist.**

**Error at** import com.payumoney.sdkui.ui.utils.PayUmoneyFlowManager;

tried to add dependency **implementation 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.6.1'** in build.gradle.

**After adding dependency tried to build project:**

Error Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs.

**Logs at AndroidManifest.xml**

Merging Errors: Warning Namespace 'com.payu.custombrowser' used in: AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml. payu-custom-browser:7.9.0 manifest Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#com.payu.custombrowser.PreLollipopPaymentsActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. main manifest (this file), line 24

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` for `PreLollipopPaymentsActivity` in your module's AndroidManifest.xml file.

> android:exported: Flag indicating whether the given application component is available to other applications. If false, it can only be accessed by applications with its same user id (which usually means only by code in its own package). If true, it can be invoked by external entities, though which ones can do so may be controlled through permissions. The default value is false for activity, receiver, and service components that do not specify any intent filters; it is true for activity, receiver, and service components that do have intent filters (implying they expect to be invoked by others who do not know their particular component name) and for all content providers

Comment: i have already mention in it.

Comment: You did not explicitly state whether or not you added the `android:exported` tag to AndroidManifest.xml. Can you please post your AndroidManifext.xml file?  That's where this issue is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to implement the Payu-money then it will help you,
I've implemented it successfully
checkout this link with reference code [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571151/payucheckoutpro-android-sdk-implementation-issue/74601158#74601158)